# converting xml database data from web api into json in xamarin with c#

Tags: c#, xamarin

this is `deserialazeing` `xml` data that come from web api
The problem is result is null.`ip` address in `ApiUrl` come from `iis`
i think ApiUrl cant gain data from iis .so get problem

```
public class ApiRepository
{
    public static string ApiUrl = "http://192.168.1.6:8085";
    public List<Ads> GetAllAds()
    {       
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {   
            var result = client.GetStringAsync(ApiUrl + "/allads").Result;
            var ads = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Ads>>(result);
            return ads;
        }
            
    }
}
```

Comment: please proofread and [Edit].  Your formatting is completely broken and your post is impossible to read.

Comment: Another thing to note is that that URL is a URL that is probably running on your local machine, your device/emulator/simulator won't be able to reach your PC. To do so, on Android emualtors you can do the following url: 10.0.2.2:8085, 10.0.2.2 is a local loop back to your machine; it maps itself to 127.0.0.1 (NOT LOCALHOST) on the host machine

Comment: ** i change the 'ip' address but not solve problem